# Trying to use cypress test fails if imported component contains svg

Tags: reactjs, testing, svg, cypress

Trying to use cypress test fails if imported component contains svg

here is the svg and the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280 1280" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
    <g transform="matrix(0.1,0,0,-0.1,0,1280)">
        <path d="M1067,11733L0,10665L2132,8533L4265,6400L2132,4267L0,2135L1067,1067L2135,0L6400,4265L8533,2132L10665,0L11733,1067L12800,2135L10668,4267L8535,6400L12800,10665L11733,11733L10665,12800L8533,10668L6400,8535L4267,10668L2135,12800L1067,11733Z" style="fill:rgb(223,59,59);fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

ParseError : unexpected token

any ideas on why  is failing on the xml declaration?

Comment: How are you running the cypress tests, and what happens when you visit the site normally?

Comment: Hi - just this simple setup


```
    import React from 'react' 
    Import mycomponent from ""my componentwiththesvgprobplem" 
    import { mount } from 'cypress-react-unit-test' 
    import '@testing-library/cypress/add-commands'
```

and get the import error on the component with the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing quotation mark after standalone?

Comment: oops, sorry that was just me copying over the error. They syntax is actually ok in the file . Thank you though for your comment.